# How do I skip blank rows rather than printing out the State ID with a bunch of zeros after

Tags: java, debugging

Right now the code works but, it prints out line 3 even though there is no data for number 3 so it follows with a bunch of zeros. How can I skip blanks instead?

```
//DataManager.java


import java.io.*;

public class DataManager {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DataManager dataManager = new DataManager();
        dataManager.init();
    }

    public void init() {
        Row dataSet[] = new Row[13486]; // current number of rows in the dataset

        // read the data
        try (FileReader fr =
                 new FileReader("SmallAreaIncomePovertyEstData.txt")) {
            int c;
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;
            char rowInputs[] = new char[1130]; // number of characters per row

            while ((c = fr.read()) != -1) {
                rowInputs[i] = (char) c;
                i++;
                if (c == 10) { // `32` is blank space, '10' is new line
                    dataSet[j] = new Row(rowInputs);
                    j++;
                    i = 0;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("I/O Error: " + e);
        }

        // manipulate the data
        this.manipulateData(dataSet);

        // write the data
    }

    public Row[] manipulateData(Row[] dataset) {
        Row[] manipulatedData = new Row[57];

        try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(
                 "../SmallAreaIncomePovertyEstDataManipulated.txt"))) {
            int stateId = 1; // starting point id
            int statePopulation = 0;
            int stateChildPopulation = 0;
            int stateChildPovertyPopulation = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < dataset.length; i++) {
                if (dataset[i].id == stateId) {
                    statePopulation += dataset[i].population;
                    stateChildPopulation += dataset[i].childPopulation;
                    stateChildPovertyPopulation +=
                        dataset[i].childPovertyPopulation;
                } else {
                    double stateChildPovertyPopulationPercentage = 0;
                    if (stateChildPopulation != 0) {
                        stateChildPovertyPopulationPercentage =
                            (double) stateChildPovertyPopulation
                            / stateChildPopulation * 100;
                        int z = 12;
                    } else {
                        stateChildPovertyPopulationPercentage = 0;
                    }
                    bw.append(stateId + " \t " + statePopulation + " \t "
                        + stateChildPopulation + " \t "
                        + stateChildPovertyPopulation + " \t "
                        + stateChildPovertyPopulationPercentage + "\n");
                    statePopulation = 0;
                    stateChildPopulation = 0;
                    stateChildPovertyPopulation = 0;
                    i--;
                    stateId++;
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("I/O Error: " + e);
        }

        int x = 12;
        return manipulatedData;
    };

    public class Row {
        private char[] contents;
        private int id;
        private int population;
        private int childPopulation; // Population of Relevant Children 5 to 17
                                     // years of Age
        private int childPovertyPopulation; // Estimated Number of Relevant
                                            // Children 5 to 17 years old
        //                     in Poverty Related to the Householder
        private double percentageChildPovertyPopulation;
        Row(char[] input) {
            contents = input;
            char[] stateIdPlaceholder = java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(
                contents, 0, 2); // state id [char range]
            id = Integer.parseInt(new String(stateIdPlaceholder).trim());
            char[] tPopPlaceholder = java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(
                contents, 83, 90); // total poulation [char range]
            population = Integer.parseInt(new String(tPopPlaceholder).trim());
            char[] cPopPlaceholder = java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(
                contents, 92, 99); // child population [char range]
            childPopulation =
                Integer.parseInt(new String(cPopPlaceholder).trim());
            char[] cPPopPlaceholder = java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(
                contents, 101, 108); // child poverty population [char range]
            try {
                childPovertyPopulation =
                    Integer.parseInt(new String(cPPopPlaceholder).trim());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
}

//DataPresenter.java

import java.io.*;
public class DataPresenter {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
           System.out.println("File: ../SmallAreaIncomePovertyEstDataManipulated.txt");           
           System.out.println("Id" + " \t " + "Population" + " \t " + "ChildPop" + " \t " + "CPovPop" + " \t \t" + "CPovPop%" + "\t");


        // read the data
        try ( FileReader fr = new FileReader("../SmallAreaIncomePovertyEstDataManipulated.txt"))
        {
            int c;
            while((c = fr.read()) != -1) {
                System.out.print((char) c);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("I/O Error: " + e);
        }

    }
}
```

[When the code compiles and runs, the data is not properly aligned to all of the columns. How do I get them to line up like they are supposed to?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AffEi.png)